# Function in not defined in custom jquery when using href=javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to setup slider. When i connect jquery library just as `<script src="></script>` and connect slider code just as `<script></script>` with no  `require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui']`, all works fine.

But when i try to connect script through magento jquery and delete link to jquery library, script won't work and shows error `Uncaught ReferenceError: slide is not defined`

Also when I am trying to connect custom jquery code via `requirejs-config.js` i got the same error.

So how make it works through right way (with no external jquery library)?

Here is part of HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:slide('right');">LEFT</a>
```

Jquery code:

```
      require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function ($){

            function slide(direction) {
                    var slider_full_width = $('.slides_box li').outerWidth() + 28;


                    if (direction == 'left') {
                        var left_sliding = parseInt($('.slides_box').css('left')) + slider_full_width;
                    } else {
                        var left_sliding = parseInt($('.slides_box').css('left')) - slider_full_width;

                    }

                    $('.slides_box:not(:animated)').animate({'left': left_sliding}, 350, function () {
                        if (direction == 'left') {
                            $('.slides_box li:first').before($('.slides_box li:last'));
                        }
                        else {
                            $('.slides_box li:last').after($('.slides_box li:first'));
                        }
                        $('.slides_box').css({'left': '0'});
                    });
                }
          });
```

EDIT: I have an idea why it don't work. Because after adding requirement of magento jquery it render my custom code inside `$(document).ready(function() {`, but javascript href works only outside of ready function. Anyway i don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="slide('right');">LEFT</a>
```

```
<script>
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function ($){

        slide=function(direction) {
            var slider_full_width = $('.slides_box li').outerWidth() + 28;


            if (direction == 'left') {
                var left_sliding = parseInt($('.slides_box').css('left')) + slider_full_width;
            } else {
                var left_sliding = parseInt($('.slides_box').css('left')) - slider_full_width;

            }

            $('.slides_box:not(:animated)').animate({'left': left_sliding}, 350, function () {
                if (direction == 'left') {
                    $('.slides_box li:first').before($('.slides_box li:last'));
                }
                else {
                    $('.slides_box li:last').after($('.slides_box li:first'));
                }
                $('.slides_box').css({'left': '0'});
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The same error.

Comment: It's tested code. Clear cache. It's working fine here.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It works. Thank you. Is it problem only in href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="slide('right');"?

Comment: Ok, i see a new variable in function. Thank you.